# Is there way to create regions for view modes programmatically?

Tags: theming, entities

So I have programmatically created a view mode and I need to theme it. The view mode will be rendered via views modules for different content types and The structure requires that I separate fields into to separate regions. A image region and content region. The different content types will be able to choose the fields they want for each region. So event may use featured image, while news article can use hero image field.

[image]

I really don't wan't to use display suite if there is some programmatic way of doing this.

Comment: use template files and create your own regions using divs

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to theme the fields behaving like a css-grid-system, maybe provided by your theme. Name view field templates like this:

```
views-view-field--foobar--page--field_name.tpl.php
```

And

- Make sure they have the correct order in the view.
- Empty fields wont be displayed.

If they have different names for the different content types, just include all field-names in your selectors ..

Maybe also have a look in the [docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!views-view-field.tpl.php/7), and views have name suggestions under `Advanced` -> `Theme`: Click on `Information`